# How to get app version which is uploaded on Playstore using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, version

I want to know the app version that is uploaded on Playstore so that users can know the new application is on Playstore. I can use appUpdateManager but it doesn't let me know the version of application. It only tells me the available version code and boolean whether app can be updated or not.

There is also parsing the url and know the app version on playstore but I don't think it is good idea. Is there any ways to know the app version on play store without parsing the url and appUpdateManager?

Comment: I think it's better , if you could save the latest verison in a server and compare on startup with the current version. Or You can scrap the play store web page and get the value

Comment: but is it good idea to scrap the play store web page and get the value? because I think scrapping the play store web page can not be working if the webpage on playstore changes

Comment: Other than that , I couldn't find any api to do that

Comment: Ok, I also think that storing the latest version in a server is a best way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: that's much better , the AppUpdateManager also takes sometime to identify a new update